# div under a button javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show a hidden div called "laila" right under a button ,
this is my code :

```
    <html>
    Disable dates before:<input type="text"><input style="width:20;height:25" type="button" value="myButton" onclick="show()">
    <script>
    function show(){
    document.getElementById("laila").style.display="block"; 
    }
    </script>
    <div id ="laila" style="display: none"><table border="1"><tr><td>laila</td></tr></table></div>

    </html>
```

how can I place the div under "myButton" ?

Comment: Do you mean lined up underneath the button? (ie, left edge of DIV is left edge of button)

Comment: What do you mean by "under" - is this just a styling question? If yes, the DOM already contains the proper order of elements, so you could just style appended element accordingly...

Comment: @user1090190 Yes , (the div's size doesn't matter)

Comment: @Laila92 If you want it to be dynamic (pretend the button moves, the div will appear beneath new button location) you'll need to set the DIV to position absolute and set it's style.top property to position of the button (received through offsetTop and then looping through all of its parents elements and adding their offsetTop as well) + its offsetHeight + the space between you want - then do the same for style.left. Judging by your code I'm assuming you're just starting to play around with JS, though, and I'm sure someone will give you a simpler way until you get your feet a little more wet.

Comment: @Arthur P ok but how to change its position horizontally

Comment: To horizontal position adjusting - just grab the left/margin/padding attributes of the button element and reapply them to the div

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
        function show() {
            document.getElementById("laila").style.display = "block";
        }
    </script>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Disable dates before:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text"><input style="width: 20; height: 25" type="button"   value="myButton"
                        onclick="show()">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="laila" style="display: none">
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    laila
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: did you try it. you want div to under button. this code do this.